# T-sql query to get running difference for applied leave

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my table :

[image]

i need to get running difference of applied leave with above table . here applied leave is 10 and total balance is 8 . i need to display -2 on the last line (8-10=-2).

My try:

```
 ;WITH x AS
(
    select abs(balance-(applied))req  from mytest where rno=1 
    UNION ALL
    select abs(mytest.balance-abs(x.req))  from x join  mytest on  mytest.rno=x.rno+1
)
SELECT balance, balance-req
    FROM x
```

Actual Result:

[image]

Expected Result:

```
balance |   applied
5.00    |       0
2.00    |       0
1.00    |       -2
```

can anyone help to sort this issue???... thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUM` and `OVER` combined with `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` to calculated the running difference for each row:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [rno] INT
   ,[balance] DECIMAL(9,2)
   ,[applied] DECIMAL(9,2)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([rno], [balance], [applied])
VALUES (1, 5, 10)
      ,(2, 2, 0)
      ,(3, 1, 0);

SELECT [rno]
      ,[balance]
      ,SUM([balance] - [applied]) OVER (ORDER BY [rno] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [applied]
FROM @DataSource;
```

[image]

Setting `0` to the rest of the running differences (except the last one) can be done with additional manipulation or with `IIF` if you know the `ID` of the last row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions for this.  The key would be a cumulative sum of balance:

```
select t.rno, t.balance, t.applied,
       (case when max_rno = rno then cume_balance - sum_applied
             else 0
        end) as new_applied
from (select t.*,
             sum(balance) over (order by rno) as cume_balance,
             max(rno) over () as max_rno,
             sum(applied) over () as sum_applied
      from mytable t
     ) t;
```